# field identifier '0' does not exist in table dirpartymap

Tags: x++, dynamics-365

I am creating a `tab` with address `grid` like `vendtable` `form`.
I am using this method on this [Webpage](https://dynamicszerotohero.blogspot.com/2020/03/add-address-tab-on-custom-form-d365fo.html) but when I open the tab it throws this error "field identifier '0' does not exist in table dirpartymap"

Comment: While implementing the linked post, I ran into some issues, but not the error mentioned in the question. Without having access to the implementation, it is hard to guess what the issue might be. You can compare the implementation with [mine](https://github.com/FH-Inway/stack-overflow/commit/89a4a9228181dc858ec19368c421c958316e9451), maybe that will help finding a solution.